# What's the smallest animal with hemoglobin running in its veins?

Tags: zoology, hematology

What's the smallest known animal with hemoglobin running in its veins?

Here I mean an animal that on its own is able to produce the hemoglobin that is running in its veins. For that reason this excludes mosquitoes that have filled themselves with blood from another creature, for example.

With smallest I mean either by mass or by spatial dimensions. Either would be interesting.

Comment: Smallest by mass?

Comment: thanks @AlanBoyd, I have now updated that in my question:-)

Comment: What kind of googling have you done? It sounds like a "homework" question to me (not that it comes from actual homework)

Comment: The scope of the question is still unclear. Some definitions of 'haemoglobin' include proteins found in invertebrates and even in microbes. By using the expression 'running in its veins' do you aim to exclude such organisms?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? What will it tell you? Anything other than an entry in the Guinness Book of Records?

Comment: Why veins? Why not arteries?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends how different from human hemoglobin it can be and still count as hemoglobin.  Here is a cool evolutionary tree of globins.
[image]
http://www.mhhe.com/biosci/genbio/enger/student/olc/art_quizzes/genbiomedia/0329.jpg

Here is the worlds smallest fish.  Fish have hemoglobin similar to that of humans.
from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_smallest_fish):  The world's smallest fish is *Paedocypris progenetica*[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7FNl.jpg) from Indonesia, with mature females measuring 7.9 mm (0.31 in).

[image]

But I think bloodworms are even smaller. They have hemoglobin too.  It is evolutionarily more distant from us but they use it for the same reason we do.

[image]
from https://www.prestoninnovations.com/img/media/Seq-7.jpg

http://www.allaboutworms.com/the-basics-of-blood-worms

> Blood worms are red because their blood plasma contains haemoglobin,
>   like human blood. Also spelled “hemoglobin,” haemoglobin increases its
>   ability to take up oxygen. The larvae commonly burrow in the
>   oxygen-poor mud bottom of pools and rivers, so haemoglobin is of great
>   value to the larvae.

If you are going to allow very distant relatives,  I think this snail is even smaller than the smallest bloodworm.  Less than 1 mm.  Molluscs have hemoglobin too.

[image]
from https://www.slideshare.net/fmoretzsohn/texas-seashellsmore-than-you

Answer (score 4):

*Paedophryne amauensis*, the world's smallest vertebrate by length, 7.7mm. The coin by the way is an American dime.

[image]